# YouTube embed doesn't autoplay on initial load. Will autoplay on refresh

Tags: html, youtube, autoplay, ytplayer

This is the live website with the issue: thebishops.band

When I set `mute=1`, `autoplay` on initial load works. But I need the audio to play.

Using `data-property` vs. `<iframe/>`.

Here is the html:

```
<section class="intro full-width full-height jIntro" id="anchor00">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="playerVideo" data-property="{videoURL:'LH-Jm6QdebU',showControls:false,containment:'self',autoPlay:1, mute:false, startAt:0,opacity:1,ratio:'4/3', addRaster:true}"> <!-- Slider -->
        <a href="#" class="play-video">Play/Pause</a>
    </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the recent YouTube API update and [browsers vendor policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes), you can’t
autoplay a video if the audio is on. Following is the excerpt from the update:

> **Chrome's autoplay policies are simple:**
>
> Muted autoplay is always allowed.
>
> Autoplay with sound is allowed if:
>
> - User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
> - On desktop,
>   the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning
>   the user has previously play video with sound.
> - On mobile, the user has
>   [added the site to their home screen]. Top frames can delegate
>   autoplay permission to their iframes to allow autoplay with sound.

I believe you are using [jquery.mb.YTPlayer](https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer) library. It has a workaround that if the autoplay is set to true and the audio is not muted the video start once the user has the first click/touch interaction with the page.

Comment: I actually did, but it says that because I have less than 15 reputation it doesn’t count. I just started my account. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @SeanDraper if this answer solved your problem, please consider [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Thank you.